# Redirect only sub pages using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have a website (WordPress multisite) for which I've moved a bunch of content from the route domain (http://domain[dot]com) to a sub domain (http://sub.domain[dot]com). Now I need to direct users to all the pages of the route site (http://domain[dot]com/page) to their new location (http://sub.domain[dot]com/page). But... and here's the bit I'm really struggling with... I need to omit the route url from this re-write as there is another 'geo-redirect' in place that I need to not affect. What I need to do therefore is redirect ONLY those sub page and NOT the parent/main domain.

Here's (a recent iteration) of what I'm working with:

```
# ignore the home page, not working :(
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(.*)\.routetogreatness\.com$ [NC]
# redirect all the sub pages, works
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^routetogreatness.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://global.routetogreatness.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Any help will be very gratefully received.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are searching for is a condition that checks if the file that is requested is not a filename. That's what `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`. It is true if `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` (I believe an absolute path to a file on the server, based on the request), is not a file. (Please note: I haven't tested this code as I don't have access to a server at this location, but I think it should work.)

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://sub.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

An other solution would be to only rewrite the url if the requested url contains a slash. It would redirect `domain.com/folder/index.php`, but not `domain.com/index.php`.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([^/]+)/(.+)$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://sub.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: OMG. Thanks so much for that fast response Sumurai8, that second one totally nailed it (the fist one not so much). I should have posted my question two hours ago! Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so the above solution didn't quite work out for me as it turned out that while this worked beautifully on sub/child page, it would skip over parent pages as well as the home page (like domain/news for example. I've eventually run with this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://sub.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

This just skips over the home page or root URL and redirects everything else, even 404s.